# Settxfee does not work in RPC

Tags: bitcoind, transaction-fees

I am using settxfee(0.00020) before sendtoaddress RPC call however after sending 0.042 in blockchain a fee of 0.000045 is showing.

How can I set the fee properly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`settxfee` sets the transaction fee per kilobyte, as that is the relevant unit for prioritization on the network and in blocks.

With `sendtoaddress` the size (in bytes) is not known ahead of time, so you can't set the exact fee.

Comment: is there a way i can implement a dynamic fee for my transactions ?

Comment: What does dynamic fee mean?

Comment: fee that will vary based on network load so that my transaction will confirm 100%

Comment: If you don't use settxfee, Bitcoin Core will use the results of automatic fee estimation.

Comment: @PieterWuille really? since which version?

Comment: @knocte: I think since [0.12.0](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.12.0#wallet-transaction-fees).

Comment: do you have the source for that?

Comment: https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.12.0#wallet-transaction-fees

Answer (score 1):

What version of bitcoind do you have?

That is known issue about updated bitcoind server. Calculation of transaction size has been changed. Before update, transaction with 255 bytes size was rounded *up* to 1 Kb and your settxfee value was used. But now, it calculates accurate value of transaction size and calculates fee according to it, without rounding up.

Read here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/7633